# Xcode 64BitConversion not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, 32bit-64bit

I have a Cordova project, of which the iOS code needs to support 64-bit.
So the Apple Developer page (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/ConvertingExistingApp/ConvertingExistingApp.html) 
has a "Conversion Procedure" which involves a ConvertCocoa64 program.

The page refers to this path:
`/Developer/Extras/64BitConversion/ConvertCocoa64`, 
however I cannot seem to find it anywhere.
If I try cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/, there is no "Extras" folder to be found.

*I'm running Os X Yosemite with Xcode version 6.3.1*

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find how to run the script?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that everything that was in **/Developer** is now embedded in the Xcode folder. Some items aren't included by default you can download it from [apple download](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)

You want the "Auxiliary Tools" for your version of Xcode.